# Curl Is Not Recognized , Using Popen()

Tags: python, windows, curl, python-2.7

```
p = Popen(["curl", "http://localhost:8983/solr/update/json?commit=true", "--data-binary", "@solrData.json", "-H", "Content-type:application/json"], cwd=r"C:/Users/SOLR/docs", shell=True)
```

This the code I am using right now, and I get the error that curl is not recognized.
When I run the command in the same dir where the solrData.json file is:

```
curl "http://localhost:8983/solr/update/json?commit=true" --data-binary @solrData.json -H "Content-type:application/json"
```

it runs perfectly. Curl is in the system path and there everthing works.
Also as a comparison this works just fine:

```
p = Popen("java -jar post.jar solrData.xml", cwd=r"C:/Users/SOLR/docs")
```

**EDIT**

```
    import requests
# open the file to upload
        with open('C:/Users/SOLR/docs/solrData.json', 'rb') as fin:
            # execute the post request
            headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json'}
            r = requests.post("http://localhost:8983/solr/update/json", params=dict(commit="true"), headers=headers, data=fin.read())
```

This is the solution that works. Thank you zmo and Martijn Pieters for your help.

Answer (score 2):

You are passing in a *list* of arguments, but set `shell=True`. Switch off the latter (remove the argument, `False` is the default) and let Python handle the command:

```
p = Popen(["curl", "http://localhost:8983/solr/update/json?commit=true", "--data-binary", "@solrData.json", "-H", "Content-type:application/json"], cwd=r"C:/Users/SOLR/docs")
```

Note that it'll be vastly simpler to install the [`python-requests`](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) library and do the whole task from Python with minimal fuss:

```
import requests

with open('C:/Users/SOLR/docs/solrData.json', 'r') as solrdata:
    r = requests.post('http://localhost:8983/solr/update/json?commit=true',
        data=solrdata, headers={'Content-type': 'application/json'})
```

Comment: @user2485334: What does `import os; print os.environ['PATH']` say? Does that path include the directory where `curl` is located?

Comment: @user2485334: Under the hood, Python uses the [`CreateProcess` call](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425(v=vs.85).aspx) to execute `curl`; you can see from the linked page where Windows will look for the command.

Answer (score 0):

from [Popen manpage](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor):

> *On Unix with shell=True, the shell defaults to /bin/sh. If args is a string, the string specifies the command to execute through the shell. This means that the string must be formatted exactly as it would be when typed at the shell prompt. This includes, for example, quoting or backslash escaping filenames with spaces in them. If args is a sequence, the first item specifies the command string, and any additional items will be treated as additional arguments to the shell itself. That is to say, Popen does the equivalent of:*

```
Popen(['/bin/sh', '-c', args[0], args[1], ...])
```

> *On Windows with shell=True, the COMSPEC environment variable specifies the default shell. The only time you need to specify shell=True on Windows is when the command you wish to execute is built into the shell (e.g. dir or copy). You do not need shell=True to run a batch file or console-based executable.*

So you need to issue the following command:

```
p = Popen(["curl", "http://localhost:8983/solr/update/json?commit=true", "--data-binary", "@solrData.json", "-H", "Content-type:application/json"], cwd=r"C:/Users/SOLR/docs", shell=False)
```

but why do you want to use subprocess to use curl, whereas you have the [`pycurl`](http://pycurl.sourceforge.net/) library that makes it easier to use curl? Here's a code inspired by [the file upload example](http://pycurl.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/pycurl/pycurl/examples/file_upload.py?revision=1.5&content-type=text/plain):

```
import os
import pycurl
import cStringIO

# here's a handler to expose the read_callback method
class FileReader:
    def __init__(self, fp):
        self.fp = fp
    def read_callback(self, size):
        return self.fp.read(size)

# here's a buffer to handle the output of the pycurl request
buf = cStringIO.StringIO()

# we open the file
with open('solrData.json', 'rb') as fin:
    # get its size
    filesize = os.path.getsize('solrData.json')

    # initiates curl
    c = pycurl.Curl()

    # setup curl (url, as a post request, file upload size and content, content-type and output buffer)
    c.setopt(c.URL, 'http://localhost:8983/solr/update/json?commit=true')
    c.setopt(pycurl.POST, 1)
    c.setopt(pycurl.POSTFIELDSIZE, filesize)
    c.setopt(pycurl.READFUNCTION, FileReader(f).read_callback)
    c.setopt(pycurl.HTTPHEADER, ["Content-type: application/json"])
    c.setopt(c.WRITEFUNCTION, buf.write)

    # we execute the query
    c.perform()

    # and write the result of the query
    with open('C:/Users/SOLR/docs/result.json') as f:    
        f.write(buf.getvalue())
    # and finally we close the buffer
    buf.close()
```

or even simpler than using `pycurl`, you can use the [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) library:

```
import requests

# open the file to upload
with open('solrData.json', 'rb') as fin:
    # execute the post request
    headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json'}
    r = requests.post("http://httpbin.org/get", params=dict(commit=True), headers=headers, data=fin.read())
    # write the result
    with open('C:/Users/SOLR/docs') as f:
        f.write(f.text) # write the json data in text file
        print f.json() # print the json content as python datatypes
```

HTH

Comment: The `pycurl` API is truly horrendous; I can never bring myself to recommending it, even over the command-line interface. You have the file use the wrong way around; `curl` will POST the contents of the file (upload it), not download it.

Comment: Firstly: code with shell=False does not work and still gives me System can not find file error. Secondly: I need to give curl the additional parameters:   "--data-binary", "@solrData.json", "-H", "Content-type:application/json"   how would I do that with pycurl?

Comment: oh, damn... I totally agree with you about the `pycurl` API. I only gave it to tell the OP he has other better options than calling the `curl` command through `subprocess`. And that's why I gave him the even better and more elegant solution to use `requests`.

Comment: oh, I misread the curl request. I'm amending my answer for posting the file too.

Comment: the address is in the command just a parameter, I still need the other arguments so the upload would work

Comment: @user2485334 here you have the amended codes. I strongly suggest you to use the `requests` library instead of `pycurl`. As you can see, it's way simpler to use and understand: 6 lines versus 19 lines!

Comment: well unfortunately I can not update solr without using curl... is there any other way I could execute that command from my python code ?

Comment: @user2485334: Nonsense; SOLR accepts any properly formatted HTTP connections. `curl` is just a HTTP client, just like the `requests` library. Have you actually tried our suggestions?

Comment: @user2485334, `curl` is just a tool like many others. You can even forge your SOLR HTTP request using your favorite browser (given you have the correct extension to forge POST requests)

Comment: I apologize for the nonsense. I read the solr json update wiki and it only showed one way to update solr, so I thought, it was the only way. Thank you guys for your time and help.

Comment: don't hesitate to accept an answer (the checkmark) if you think that Martijn or I helped you solve your issue.